# onMessage: callback called twice on incoming messages Flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

In my app, for the web version, I use package `firebase 7.3.0` for Firebase services and I'm now setting up FCM for web too.
When I get a new message with the app in foreground the `onMessage:` from `messaging()` gets triggered twice. It also used to happen for the `flutter_messaging` device plugin prior to a certain Flutter version but is now solved.

I basically set a `StreamTransformer` to get the message in the same type of `Map<String, dynamic>` as the `flutter_messaging` device package used in `PlatformPushNotificationDevice`, I use a Stub to switch classes depending on the platform.
In the web class `PlatformPushNotificationWeb` I instantiate messaging as `var firebaseMessaging = messaging();` and declare my methods, one of which is `onMessage()` :

```
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> onMessage()  async* {

    print('PlatformPushNotificationWeb.onMessage() started');
    handleData(Payload payload, EventSink<Map<String, dynamic>> sink) {
        Map<String,dynamic> message = {
          'notification': {
            'title': payload.notification.title,
            'body': payload.notification.body,
            'sound': true
          },
          'data': payload.data
        };
      sink.add(message);
    }

    final transformer = StreamTransformer<Payload, Map<String, dynamic>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: handleData);

    yield* firebaseMessaging.onMessage.transform(transformer);
  }
```

so the listener in my bloc will receive the same message type no matter the platform,

```
Stream<PushNotificationState> _mapListenToMessagesToState(ListenToMessages event) async* {
    print('_mapListenToMessagesToState started');
    _pushNotificationSwitcher.onMessage().listen((message) {
      print('_mapListenToMessagesToState onMessage() listener: received new message');
      add(ReceivedNewMessage(message: message));
    });
  }
```

but for every incoming message I get the listener responding twice.

I set the `index.html` as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>fixit cloud biking</title>
  <!--  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">-->
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<!--  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">-->
</head>
<!--<body>-->
<body id="app-container">
<script src="main.dart.js?version=45" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>


<script>
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
     //navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
  });
}
</body>
</html>
```

and the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file as :

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-messaging.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxxx",
            authDomain: "xxxx",
            databaseURL: "xxxx",
            projectId: "xxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
            appId: "xxx",
            measurementId: "G-xxxx",
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

    const promiseChain = clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true
        })
        .then(windowClients => {
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                windowClient.postMessage(payload);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return registration.showNotification("New Message");
        });
    return promiseChain;
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('notification received: ', event)
});
```

Could it be that instantiating messaging in the `PlatformPushNotificationWeb` class and in the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file the reason of `onMessage:` callback being triggered twice?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out..a good flutter clean, Android Studio and machine restart solved it..

Now I'm not receiving the same message twice, but for those who actually are experimenting duplicate messages this will solve it, dough it's just a workaround.

Just declared  `int lastMessageId = 0` variable.
When a message comes in, check its `id` against it and, only if they're different, save the new message id as `lastMessageId` and display the message.

```
Stream<PushNotificationState> _mapListenToMessagesToState(ListenToMessages event) async* {
    print('_mapListenToMessagesToState started');
    int lastMessageId = 0;

    _pushNotificationSwitcher.onMessage().listen((message) {
      print('incoming message is : $message');
      var data = message['data'];
      int messageId = int.parse(data['id']);

      if( lastMessageId != messageId) {
        lastMessageId = messageId;
        print(
            '_mapListenToMessagesToState onMessage() listener: received new message');
        add(ReceivedNewMessage(message: message));
      }
    });
  }
```